# Why would a maven project that compiles successfully using IntelliJ's maven lifecycle fail with mvn commands in terminal?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, maven-3

I can compile and build my maven cucumber project successfully via the in-built Maven window in IntelliJ, for example, `clean` and then `install`.

[image]

If I run the same project via terminal - `mvn clean install` I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project AutomationFrameworkSkeleton: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

My understanding is that the lifecycles in the Maven window in IntelliJ do the same job as running `mvn` commands in the terminal. Is this understanding incorrect? Why the discrepancy in results? Are they not using the same `jdk` configurations?

Comment: As the error message says: "Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

Comment: And that is pretty plausible IDEA selects the JDK, and when you use the terminal the JDK/Java from your path is used.

Comment: @M.P. Korstanje, So what's the possible solution? I have checked JDK for importer settings in IntelliJ to ensure that jdk path is selected. I cant see jre path specified anywhere in the project

Comment: I dunno. That depends on what JVM or JDKS you have on your path.  Do bear in mind that the console and idea are different systems so setting anything in IDEA has no bearing on the console. So you may well stop looking at IDEA and debug the problem as a console only problem.

Comment: `mvn --version` should  usually prints some useful diagnostics

Comment: And then check the documentation for maven to see how it detects the JVM or JDK.